# Elastic Search Unique Field Values

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get groups of **only unique values in Elastic Search** for the searches. I can't figure out why this doesn't behave.

I have gone through many StackOverflow questions, and read the Documentation for most of the day. Nothing seems to work for me, below I provided what I tried doing last.

Is there any reason someone would want to have the same results repeatedly returned? Maybe for differing versions of a Document?

---

In this example I would like a listing of all `mfr_id`'s, and their `mfr_desc` as well. I am running this over a type to search document field values only. It seems that Agg Terms is the way to accomplish this, does anyone see anything I am doing wrong?

---

**1: API Call**

```
GET /inventory/item/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "_source": ["mfr_id", "mfr_desc"], 
  "aggs": {
    "unique_vals": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "mfr_id.keyword"  
        /** I have to use .keyword, seems like my mappings isn't working */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**2: Mapping File**

The Mapping I run after doing a Bulk import is quite simple. I read to not analyze the keys if you want a unique query:

```
{
  "index": "inventory",
  "body": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_default_": {
        "properties": {
          "mfr_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**3: My Results**
Aggregation has ~10 records when there are about 100. I would really like to be able to get the `_source` fields of more than just a key if this is possible.

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 49341,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "unique_vals": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 6815,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "14",
          "doc_count": 24292
        },
        {
          "key": "33",
          "doc_count": 5508
        },
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would really like to be able to get the _source fields of more than
>   just a key if this is possible.

I think , you have only one option , I have faced same problem . Try this  :-

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "byId": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "mfr_id"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "byDesc": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "mfr_desc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you will get both id and desc while iterating through Elastic search JAVA API .

```
Terms aTerms = aAggregations.get("byId");
aTerms.getBuckets().stream().forEach(aBucketById-> {
            Terms aTermsDesc = aBucketById.getAggregations().get("byDesc");
            aTermsDesc.getBuckets().stream().forEach(aBucketByDesc -> {
//store id and desc
   });
});
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I wouldn't have tried this. I am surprised the documentation is not clearer. It doesn't provide examples like this; Or if it does exist, I couldn't find it. This is very smart, I am wondering why such a feature as simple as this is so trivial. Also, you have a very nice skillset on your profile.

Comment: Thanks for your compliment :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a filter , it has better performance than an aggregation.

in aggregation you get all of the documents and only than you apply the aggregation . if you using a filter you get only the documents witch match the filter , and also filters can be cached.

```
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "mfr_id"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```